# Rails route for current user's profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm looking for advice on the best way to create paths for a current user's profile page.  Currently I only have users as a resource.  You can visit any user's profile page by going to /users/:user_id.  I also have member routes, for example, /users/:user_id/followers.  I would like to be able to have the routes /profile and /profile/followers that will bring the current user to their profile page.  So if my user id was 5 I could go to /profile and it would bring me to the same page as /users/5.

Note: I am also using devise

routes

```
  resources :users, only: [:show, :update] do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
```

users_controller

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def followers
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = "Followers"
    @users = @user.followers.active

    render 'show'
  end

  def following
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = "Following"
    @users = @user.followed_users.active

    render 'show'
  end
```

Is there a way I can use the users controller and the same actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the routes add

`get 'profile', to: 'users#show'`

In the action use `current_user` to find the user instead of `User.find(params[:id]`. Then you don't need to add the `Id` in the path.

In the `show action` you can add the following to be able to use both.

```
if params[:id]
  user = User.find(params[:id])
else
  user = current_user
end
```

Comment: I still need the action to work for visiting other user's profiles.

Comment: you need the id (or some other unique value) to know which profile you want to visit. How would you know which user to visit if there's no id (or other unique value)?

Comment: I was thinking of using an if statement in the controller action. Something like `if params[:id].nil? @user = current_user else...`  Or maybe I need to use a separate controller action.

Comment: There's a page in the Rails Guide that describes how to solve this particular situation https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources.